# How to highlight the transcript of a audio file?

Tags: javascript, audio, highlight

Im beginner in javascript so I'm very sorry for my amateurish codes.
I have a audio and some text that is subtitles of it.
I have the timestamps of conversation.
for example the timestamp of "hi" in audio is "1.525487" sec.
I want to highlight the text "hi"  in that moment.

When I use a integer number for "span id" for example "ts1" it works correctly,
but when I use decimal number like "1.525487" it dose not work.
what should I do?

Thanks for your helps.

```
<body>
<audio id = "adi" controls>
<source src="Greeting.mp3"></source>
</audio>

<div>
<pre>
A: <span id="ts1.525487">Hi</span> , <span id="ts2.193877">how are you doing?</span>
</pre>
</div>

<script>
var spns = document.getElementsByTagName("SPAN");
var audi = document.getElementById("adi");

audi.addEventListener("timeupdate", f1);
function f1(){
    var i;
    for (i = 0 ; i< spns.length ; i++){
        if(spns[i].id == "ts" + audi.currentTime){
            spns[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";  
        }
    }
}
</script>
</body>
```

Comment: What exactly is not working ? I have done some tests and everything seems to be working. Check here: https://jsfiddle.net/fx5vh936/

Comment: when I play the audio and it reaches to "1.525487" second , the text "Hi" will not highlighted.sorry for my bad english :( .

Answer (score 6, accepted):

That's because you're not dealing with a exact number. Put a `console.log(audi.currentTime)` in the event and you'll see what I mean. You have to consider a time interval not an exact time value. Here, try this way:

```
<body>
<audio id = "adi" controls>
<source src="Greetings.mp3"></source>
</audio>

<div>
<pre>
A: <span id="ts3.525487">Hi</span> , <span id="ts5.193877">how are you doing?</span>
</pre>
</div>

<script>
var spns = document.getElementsByTagName("SPAN");
var audi = document.getElementById("adi");

audi.addEventListener("timeupdate", f1);
function f1(){
    var i;  
    for (i = 0 ; i< spns.length ; i++){
    var time = Number(spns[i].id.slice(2));
        if(time < audi.currentTime){
            if (i>0) spns[i -1].style.backgroundColor = "white";  
            spns[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";  
        }
    }
}
</script>
</body>
```

Here's a running example:

```js
var spns = document.getElementsByTagName("SPAN");
var audi = document.getElementById("adi");

audi.addEventListener("timeupdate", f1);
function f1(){
  var i;  
  for (i = 0 ; i< spns.length ; i++){
    var time = Number(spns[i].id.slice(2));
    if(time < audi.currentTime){
      if (i>0) spns[i -1].style.backgroundColor = "white";  
      spns[i].style.backgroundColor = "red";  
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<audio id = "adi" controls>
<source src="https://ia802508.us.archive.org/5/items/testmp3testfile/mpthreetest.mp3"></source>
</audio>

<div>
<pre>
A: <span id="ts1.525487">Hi</span> , <span id="ts3.193877">how are you doing?</span>
</pre>
</div>
```

JSFiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/d1wryoak/2/

**Edit**

After you understand the above code, try to understand the one below. It's a more modern aproach to it.

```js
var audi = document.getElementById("adi");
audi.addEventListener("timeupdate", ()=>{
    var setBackground = (elem, color)=>elem.style.backgroundColor = color,
        last = undefined;
    Array.from(document.getElementsByTagName("SPAN")).forEach((spn)=>{
        if (!(spn.id.slice(2) < audi.currentTime)) return;
        last && setBackground(last, "white");  
        setBackground((last = spn), "red");  
    });
})
```

```html
<audio id = "adi" controls>
<source src="https://ia802508.us.archive.org/5/items/testmp3testfile/mpthreetest.mp3"></source>
</audio>

<div>
<pre>
A: <span id="ts1.525487">Hi</span> , <span id="ts3.193877">how are you doing?</span>
</pre>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/d1wryoak/4/

Comment: thank you very very much. I  must  read it  several times  to understand it.

Comment: If you liked the answer, please accept/upvote. Thanks.

Comment: yes. Iike it. how do I upvote the answer??? thank you very much I love you I struggled with this several days but it works great right now!!

Comment: To upvote an answer just click in the up arrow. Glad it worked. Thanks.